# Activating Audio System in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, audio

I wanted to get the audio system going on Arch Linux, and I followed the very concise instruction I found on Archlinux.org, but it didn't help.

Has anyone done this personally, therefore knowing the practical shortcut? I'd be glad to know of it.

Thank you.

Comment: What instructions? ALSA or Pulse? Please provide some more detail about what you tried, your system and what *didn't work*...

Comment: Honestly being a newbie I don't have enough knowledge on Linux hardware drivers, all I can see at this time is that totem loads and plays a video and everything is ok except that I get no sound on my audio output jack. :-D

Comment: Work your way methodically through the [ALSA page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Alsa) on the Arch Wiki - it should get you set up, and will at least allow you to add the required information to your question if you are still stuck.

Comment: YEAH! installing `alsa-utils` and unmuting the PCM and MASTER through `alsamixer` made it work! Thanks sooooooo much @jasonwryan! Would you please sum it all up and write it as an answer below so I can "accept" it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Arch Wiki ALSA page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Alsa) has comprehensive instructions on setting up sound. As the page notes:

> udev will automatically probe your hardware at boot, loading the corresponding kernel module for your audio card. Therefore, your sound should already be working, but upstream sources mute all channels by default.

In most cases, therefore, all you need to do is unmute the channels by installing `alsa-utils` and using `alsamixer`. You should also make sure that you add your user(s) to the `audio` group.